# Attachment in email to save with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: asp.net, email, memory, encoding, utf-8

Does anyone have an example of being able to send an email with an attachment where the attachment is saved as utf8 encoding. I have tried but when i open it in notepad it says the encoding is ascii. Note: that i dont want to save the file first.

```
// Init the smtp client and set the network credentials
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.Host = getParameters("MailBoxHost");

            // Create MailMessage
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("team@ccccc.co.nz",toAddress,subject, body);

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                byte[] contentAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(attachment);
                memoryStream.Write(contentAsBytes, 0, contentAsBytes.Length);

                // Set the position to the beginning of the stream.
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                // Create attachment
                ContentType contentType = new ContentType();
                contentType.Name = attachementname;
                contentType.CharSet = "UTF-8";

                System.Text.Encoding inputEnc = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

               Attachment attFile = new Attachment(memoryStream, contentType);

                // Add the attachment
                message.Attachments.Add(attFile);

                // Send Mail via SmtpClient
                smtpClient.Send(message);


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [BOM (byte order mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-8 at the beginning of the stream:

```
0xEF,0xBB,0xBF
```

Code:

```
byte[] bom = { 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF };
memoryStream.Write(bom, 0, bom.Length);

byte[] contentAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(attachment);
memoryStream.Write(contentAsBytes, 0, contentAsBytes.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your attachment is text, the default constructor of the `ContentType` class will set the attachment's `Content-Type` header to `application/octet-stream`, but it needs to be set to `text/plain` instead, eg:

```
ContentType contentType = new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
```

Or:

```
ContentType contentType = new ContentType(); 
contentType.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain;
```

Also, you should specify a `TransferEncoding` for the attachment, as UTF-8 is not 7bit clean (which many email systems still require), eg:

```
attFile.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
```

Or:

```
attFile.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.Base64;
```