# Special characters not getting encoded in email attachment

Tags: c#, csv, encoding

Here is the code-

```
string data = "1001,01 ░ - 02 Room,India,0";
var byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

var mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    Subject = "test",
    Body = "test body",
    From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com"),
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
};

var attach = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(byteData), new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));
attach.ContentDisposition.FileName = "test.csv";
attach.ContentType.CharSet = "utf-8";
mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attach);
```

There is a special character ░ which goes into the csv email attachment. But when the email is received, i opened the attached csv in excel and this is what i saw-

[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYRSr.jpg)

The ░ got converted into â–‘. I feel there is some issue with the encoding of email attachment.

Can someone please help me in resolving the encoding issue?

Comment: Could it be the `utf-8`?

Comment: What happens if you use `Encoding.UTF32` and `utf-32` in your code?

Comment: It's not a duplicate to your other question, but only because you didn't include this code in the other question. You really should have fixed your other question.

Comment: @Enigmativity Its related to my other question but its a different issue. so i raised separate questions. I have tried UTF-32 but that also did not help.

Comment: Adding BOM(Byte Order Mark) resolved the issue. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302513/attachment-in-email-to-save-with-utf-8-encoding